# Why are dot-separated prefixes ignored in the column list for INSERT statements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just come across some SQL syntax that I thought was invalid, but actually works fine (in SQL Server at least).

Given this table:

```
create table SomeTable (FirstColumn int, SecondColumn int)
```

The following `insert` statement executes with no error:

```
insert SomeTable(Any.Text.Here.FirstColumn, It.Does.Not.Matter.What.SecondColumn)
values (1,2);
```

The insert statement completes without error, and checking `select * from SomeTable` shows that it did indeed execute properly. See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18de0/2

SQL Server seems to just ignore anything except the last part of the column name given in the insert list.

**Actual question:**

Can this be relied upon as documented behaviour?

Any explanation about why this is so would also be appreciated.

Comment: Doubtless preserved for backward compatibility. Order by used to do similar. [That was fixed in 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178653(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was [reported as a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/311881/sql-server-incorrectly-accepts-prefixes-in-column-list-of-insert-statements) on Connect and despite initially encouraging comments the current status of the item is closed as "won't fix".

The Order by clause used to behave in a similar fashion but that one was fixed in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Thank you. For new visitors, it appears Erland Sommarskog, SQL Server MVP, submitted the Connect bug on or before 2010 (via: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/10e920a0-6d85-45ac-af77-b3a1ce58a7d1/#21487d3a-5740-409a-8406-e93de1e25c5b), and because Microsoft staff marked it "won't fix" it wasn't migrated to the SQL Server section of the Azure Feedback Forums when Microsoft retired Connect (the current link redirects to a page stating, "Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired").

Answer (score 3):

It's *unlikely* to be part of the SQL standard, given its dubious utility (though I haven't checked specifically <sup>(a)</sup>).

What's most likely happening is that it's throwing away the non-final part of the column specification because it's superfluous. You have *explicitly* stated what table you're inserting into, with the `insert into SomeTable` part of the command, and *that's* the table that will be used.

What you appear to have done here is to find a way to execute SQL commands that are less readable but have no real advantage. In that vein, it appears similar to the C code:

```
int nine = 9;
int eight = 8;
xyzzy = xyzzy + nine - eight;
```

which could perhaps be better written as `xyzzy++;` :-)

I wouldn't rely on it at all, *possibly* because it's not standard but *mostly* because it makes maintenance harder rather than easier, and because I know DBAs all over the world would track me down and beat me to death with IBM DB2 manuals, their choice of weapon due to the voluminous size and skull-crushing abilities :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I *have* checked non-specifically, at least for ISO 9075-2:2003 which dictates the SQL03 language.

Section `14.8` of that standard covers the `insert` statement and it appears that the following clause may be relevant:

> Each column-name in the insert-column-list shall identify an updatable column of T.

Without spending a huge amount of time (that document is 1,332 pages long and would take several days to digest properly), I suspect you could argue that the column *could* be identified just using the final part of the column name (by removing all the owner/user/schema specifications from it).

Especially since it appears only one target table is possible (updatable views crossing table boundaries notwithstanding):

```
<insertion target> ::= <table name>
```

Fair warning: I haven't checked later iterations of the standard so things may have changed. But I'd consider that unlikely since there seems to be no real use case for having this feature.

Comment: The code in question is generated in VB, and looks like `insert into target (s.col1, s.col2) select s.col1, s.col2 from source s` - so the `"s.col1, s.col2"` string is used twice. And of course there are actually joins and stuff so the alias is not completely superfluous. But at least I should be safe from DBA assassins :)

Answer (score 1):

I get errors when I try to run the script on SQL Server 2012 as well as SQL Server 2014 and SQL Server 2008 R2.  So you can certainly not rely on the behavior you see with sqlfiddle.

Even if this were to work, I would never rely on undocumented behavior in production code.  Microsoft will include notice of breaking changes with documented features but not undocumented ones.  So if this were an actual T-SQL parsing bug that was later fixed, it would break the mal-formed code.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking if it's documented. I don't get errors on my SQL 2012 install. What errors do you get?

Comment: The error I get with SQL Server 2012 SP1:
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Any'.

Comment: I see.. I guess I have my answer. Thanks for checking!

Comment: @Blorgbeard - This is only because of the reserved words though. The nonsensical `insert SomeTable(Nonsense.Foo.Bar.Wibble.Baa.FirstColumn, xyz.SecondColumn) values (1,2);` still works in 2012.