# SQL - INSERT statement conflicted with FOREIGN KEY constraint - Value already in parent table

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-insert

I'm aware that this question gets asked a million times, but I've already checked, double, and triple that corresponding values already exist in my parent table. I'm trying to populate a bridge table between my Albums and Artists, both of which are already populated. After getting errors in the C# program that was auto-populating, I tried inserting a single value manually, and still got the INSERT error.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Album](
    [Album ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Album Title] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Release Year] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Album] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Album ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Album-Artists]    Script Date: 3/6/2015 12:49:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Album-Artists](
    [Album ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Artist ID] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Album-Artists] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Album ID] ASC,
    [Artist ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Artists]    Script Date: 3/6/2015 12:49:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Artists](
    [Artist ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Artists Name] [nchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Artists] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Artist ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Album-Artists]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Album-Artists_Album] FOREIGN KEY([Album ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Album] ([Album ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Album-Artists] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Album-Artists_Album]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Album-Artists]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Album-Artists_Artists] FOREIGN KEY([Album ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Artists] ([Artist ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Album-Artists] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Album-Artists_Artists]
GO
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

(I've tried with and without the table quantifiers (Artists.[Artist ID], etc))

Comment: Please script out the definition of all tables involved including constraint definitions and add this to your question.

Comment: Generated scripts and threw them in

Comment: That doesn't include the foreign keys so we can see if they are configured correctly. In SSMS select the database and use "Tasks -> Generate Scripts" and it should be one of the options there.

Comment: Or alternatively locate the foreign key `FK_Album-Artists_Artists` in the treeview and just script that out individually as that is the one in the error message.

Comment: The foreign key constraints aren't shown in your script.  Also have you just tried `INSERT INTO DiscoFish.[dbo].[Album-Artists] values (10,3)`

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY([Album ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Artists] ([Artist ID])` <- See the problem?

Comment: Threw in ALTER part of the scripts that add foreign key restrictions

Answer (score 3):

Your foreign key is trying to match ArtistId to AlbumId.

This is incorrect. You need to recreate it.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Album-Artists]
  DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_Album-Artists_Artists];

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Album-Artists]
  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Album-Artists_Artists] 
  FOREIGN KEY([Artist ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Artists] ([Artist ID]);
```

Also the correct syntax for the insert is

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Album-Artists]
                         ([Album ID], [Artist ID])
VALUES        (10, 3);
```

Though [dot-separated prefixes are currently ignored in the column list for INSERT statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24235935/73226).

Finally I would avoid using spaces or `-` in object names so you don't have to continually use quoted identifiers or square brackets and can use the unquoted form.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AlbumArtists
            (AlbumId, ArtistId)
VALUES      (10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Kind of pissed at myself that it ended up being something so stupid, but that seems to be the way of it XD